# Finding a polynomial with two remainders and dividends

Tags: functions, polynomials

I need to find an equation, given the information that when divided by (x-1) it has a remainder of 2, and when divided by (x+2) the remainder is -19. I've looked at many answers to this type of question but none of them have really explained what to do. Please help!

Comment: Can you link some of the answers you've looked at? What were your thoughts about them?

Comment: This question seems most similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103023/find-a-polynomial-given-the-remainders-of-the-division-of-that-polynomial-with-3, however there are 3 dividends instead of 2. The op also didn't say how they found the degree of the equation, and those who commented didn't show how to get a final answer.

Comment: The degree of the polynomial is not determined from the given data.  If you have one solution, then adding any (polynomial) multiple of $(x-1)(x+2)$ will give another.  But if all you want is to find one solution, start by writing $p(x)=q(x)(x-1)+2$.  and then note that we also have $p(-2)=-19$.

Comment: I'm still not sure where to go from here since I don't have a quotient.

Comment: the quotient is not determined, but it doesn't have to be.  Just write out what $p(-2)=-19$ means using the expression with quotient and remainder.  That will tell you what $q(-2)$ is.  Then, any $q(x)$ with the right value at $-2$ will work.

Comment: Note:  Worth remarking that, since only two values were provided, there is a linear polynomial $p(n)=an+b$ that works.  That corresponds to the case $q(x)$ constant, in my set up,  But you can find the linear solution without all that fuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ and $m$ be two **natural numbers** which respectively represent the dividends of the polynomial we're looking for, we can write two expressions for that polynomial:

$$p_1= n(x-1) + 2$$
$$p_2= m(x+2) - 19$$

Simplifying further yields:

$$p_1= nx + (2-n)$$
$$p_2= mx+(2m-19)$$

And since, by our definition, $p_1=p_2$:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
n=m \\ 
2-n=2m-19
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The above is true, because **2 polynomials are equal to each other only if their corresponding coefficients are the same.**

Solving the equation system above yields $n=m=7$ (**2 natural numbers!**), and therefore, the polynomial that satisfies the answer for this question would be:

$$p= p1 = 7(x-1)+2 = 7x-5$$